# Get "Last Purchase Year" from Sales Data Pivot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pivoted the Customer ID against their year of purchase, so that I know how many times each customer purchased in different years:

```
Customer ID      1996  1997 ... 2019  2020
100000000000001     7     7 ...  NaN   NaN
100000000000002     8     8 ...  NaN   NaN
100000000000003     7     4 ...  NaN   NaN
100000000000004   NaN   NaN ...   21    24              
100000000000005    17    11 ...   18   NaN
```

My desired result is to append the column names with the latest year of purchase, and thus the number of years since their last purchase:

```
Customer ID      1996  1997 ... 2019  2020   Last   Recency
100000000000001     7     7 ...  NaN   NaN   1997        23 
100000000000002     8     8 ...  NaN   NaN   1997        23
100000000000003     7     4 ...  NaN   NaN   1997        23
100000000000004   NaN   NaN ...   21    24   2020         0 
100000000000005    17    11 ...   18   NaN   2019         1
```

Here is what I tried:

```
df_pivot["Last"] = 2020
k = 2020
while math.isnan(df_pivot2[k]):
    df_pivot["Last"] = k-1
    k = k-1

df_pivot["Recency"] = 2020 - df_pivot["Last"]
```

However what I got is "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

Could anyone help me to get the result I need?

Thanks a lot!

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get last year of purchase using `notna` + `cumsum` and `idxmax` along `axis=1` then subtract this last year of purchase from the max year to compute `Recency`:

```
c = df.filter(regex=r'\d+').columns
df['Last'] = df[c].notna().cumsum(1).idxmax(1)
df['Recency'] = c.max() - df['Last']
```

---

```
       Customer ID  1996  1997  2019  2020  Last  Recency
0  100000000000001   7.0   7.0   NaN   NaN  1997       23
1  100000000000002   8.0   8.0   NaN   NaN  1997       23
2  100000000000003   7.0   4.0   NaN   NaN  1997       23
3  100000000000004   NaN   NaN  21.0  24.0  2020        0
4  100000000000005  17.0  11.0  18.0   NaN  2019        1
```

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to apply "applymap(float)" to your dataFrame 
[Documentation from pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)